# How to use %LIKE% into a SQL JOIN request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, select

I have a JOIN request like this :

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.var_1 LIKE table_2.var_2
```

And I want to use `%LIKE%` instead of `LIKE`, but it doesn't work when I try it.

I want the data from `table_1.var_1 = table_2.var_2` , but also from `table_1.var_1 %LIKE% table_2.var_2`

Is it possible to do it ?

Comment: `%LIKE%` isn't a valid mysql syntax. You can use an OR condition in a join.

Answer (score 1):

Hi here use this query

```
SELECT * FROM `table_1` INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.var_1  WHERE `table_1.var_1` LIKE '%search%' OR table_2.var_2 = '%search2%'
```

and let me know if any error

first use table one condition and then use " OR " & " AND " for as per your condition

Comment: Thank's for your answer, but it does not work. because, you added "search" and "search2", but I don't have those. Actually, I want to have all the datas from table 1 which have "table2.var2" as a part of "table1.var1". Is it more clear ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a cross join with a locate would suit

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T,T1;
CREATE TABLE T(VAL VARCHAR(20));
CREATE TABLE T1(VAL VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('ABCDEF');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('AB');

SELECT T.*
FROM T
CROSS JOIN T1 
WHERE LOCATE(T1.VAL,T.VAL) > 0;

--------+
| VAL    |
+--------+
| ABCDEF |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: It looks good, but it doesn't fit. I cannot use "locate" in my SQL windows.

Comment: Try instr(t.val,t1.val) If you are getting an error using locate you may not be using mysql